# how to create a select trigger for sybase ase 12.5?

Tags: t-sql, sybase, sap-ase

trigger usually is on delete, update, insert. It means update data. 
I want to a trigger for access data. for example, when applying select on a table, then a trigger can be fired.

Is it possible to create a trigger on select for sybase ase 12.5?

Comment: The only way to look at something on access would be to use database auditing with ASE Security and the sybsecurity database.  The downside to using it, is the performance hit.  http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc31654_31644_1250/html/sag/X23329.htm

Comment: no select triggers in sybase ase. you probably want to use view where you can show user what they need to see and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

This is trigger's statement from [**documentation**](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.dc36272_1251/html/commands/X19955.htm):

```
create trigger [owner .]trigger_name
    on [owner .]table_name
    for {insert , update , delete} 
    as SQL_statements
```

as you can see, there is no option for select. 
So it's not possible.